# R function for finding beginning of a chr string

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to show the incidents happening only in 2016. The format is a chr format and looks like "2016-12-31". Is there a way to search for values only from 2016?

Current code:

```
most_fatalities_2016 <- gun_violence[which(gun_violence$date == "2016"), select = c("state", "city_or_county")]
```

I guess I'm looking for the r function that acts like the LIKE function in SQL.
Any help?

Comment: look into `dplyr::filter`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `substr()` or `grepl()`

```
gun_violence[substr(gun_violence$date,1,4)=="2016",]
```

or

```
gun_violence[grepl("^2016-",gun_violence$date),]
```

The above returns all column of the `gun_violence` data.frame. If you want to only return specific columns, you can specify those columns like this:

```
gun_violence[grepl("^2016-",gun_violence$date),c("state", "city_or_county")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be going further than what is asked, but I want to give some advice regarding the way the data is being stored and manipulated.

It may be much easier in downstream analyses if we transform this character variable into a proper date format beforehand.

Advice #2:

The `dplyr` package provides very clear syntax for manipulation of dataframes, which may be a nice introduction coming from SQL based backgrounds.

Advice #3:

Understanding and "reverse-engineering" the `dbplyr` package (https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/) may be enlightening for SQL-experienced users

```
gun_violence$date <-readr::parse_date(gun_violence$date)
```

after that, we can use many date-related functions, such as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

gun_violence %>% filter(date < today())
###
gun_violence %>% filter(year(date) == 2016) ### for the desired operation in the question
###
and so on
```